# JSP file doesn't recognize ArrayList?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Given the following preview of my JSP file in my project :

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" language="java"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@ page import="beans.UserBean"%>
<jsp:useBean id="userBean" class="beans.UserBean" scope="session" />
<jsp:useBean id="students" type="ArrayList<beans.UserBean>" scope="session" />
<jsp:useBean id="teachers" type="ArrayList<beans.UserBean>" scope="session" />
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
```

I get the following error in Eclipse :

```
Undefined type: ArrayList
```

What's wrong with it ? even though that I'm importing the `ArrayList` , Eclipse doesn't recognize it and shows the above message in the following two lines :

```
<jsp:useBean id="students" type="ArrayList<beans.UserBean>" scope="session" />
<jsp:useBean id="teachers" type="ArrayList<beans.UserBean>" scope="session" />
```

[image: For clearer picture :]

Any idea where did I go wrong ? Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure the `page import` directive is respected in `jsp:useBean`, only in scriptlets. Does the FQ class name work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `type` attribute should represent the fully qualified name of the class, not the generic declaration or so. Even more, JSP/EL is not aware of generic types in any way.

Use `java.util.ArrayList` instead:

```xml
<jsp:useBean id="students" type="java.util.ArrayList" scope="session" />
<jsp:useBean id="teachers" type="java.util.ArrayList" scope="session" />
```

All those `@page import` are unnecessary. They are only used when using *scriptlets* (those oldschool `<% %>` things which has been [discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files/3180202#3180202) since JSP 2.0).

By the way, if those arraylists are been prepared and put in the scope by a servlet beforehand and all you need is to just access them in EL, then you do **not** need those `<jsp:useBean>` tags at all. Using the `type` attribute instead of the `class` attribute hints less or more that you're *actually* using a servlet. It'll work as good without those `<jsp:useBean>` tags. See also [our servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info).